# Well documented open source project in .net

Tags: c#, .net, open-source

im seaching some good quality open source project in .net, according this topic 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-high-code-quality
i found intresting open source projects like "Sharp develop", its great because i can build & run it without problem, but i would like learn how it was developed in deep, learning from only source code without well documented classes, pattern used in project, techniques etc is difficult task. Can anyone provide information about project which i can understand easier.

thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Documentation usually pertains to the API rather than the rationale behind implementation or the underlying architectural decisions. The best advice I can give is to always look for/at tests first. This will give you a sense of what things do, and when you find an interesting bit, you can step through the test execution to see how the result was achieved. You will discover patterns, even if you don't know their formal names.

Answer (score 2):

nopCommerce - open source shopping cart.
http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I recommend iTextSharp (.NET Port of iText, written in C#), a open-source library used for PDF generation on-the-fly. I've personally worked on it..used the DLL version for my project, but was checking out the code to see how it was written..

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) is an option, John Skeet's .Net port of [Joda-Time](http://joda.org/joda-time/). The [User Guide](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/userguide/) looks good and...I mean, he's known for good quality code ;)